# Access HttpSession from servletContext in Grails BootStrap

Tags: servlets, grails, bootstrapping, httpsession

Can we access the HttpSession in Grails BootStrap via servletContext (or grailsApplication)? When user logged in to application, I stored some information on session and use them in the dynamic method beforeInsert. But I do not know how to retrieve those info on session.
Here is my Bootstrap code:

```
class BootStrap {
    def grailsApplication
    def init = { servletContext ->
        grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain").each { org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass gc ->
            gc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
                // Do something here with information stored in session
            }

            gc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
                               // Do something here with information stored in session
                    }
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

No, because a servlet context has multiple sessions. Sessions are per-user, while the context is global. So the scopes don't match.

What you can do is have a `HttpSessionListener` that listens for session creation and session removal. I guess you *can* somehow access the sessions that were serialized to disk after a server shutdown, but that would require you to interfere with native tomcat implementations (some Valve, perhaps)